# Wrapping a JFrame in a JApplet?

Tags: java, swing, applet, jframe, japplet

I've seen this asked a lot, but no definitive answers, i DON'T want to use Java Web Start, I need my program to run inside the browser, as a Applet, but when i coded it i made it using a JFrame so i could text it and execute it from any PC, now i need to embed it into my page, is there anything i can do to "wrap" my current executable .jar in a applet so i can embed it. or would it require i rebuild my entire program?

I have tried Java Web Start already and it doesn't suit my needs.

Thank you for any help you can provide

Comment: It really doesn't take much to convert a `JFrame` project to a `JApplet` They're almost identical in structure. Only thing is you don't need an `main` method, but you need an `init` method. If you properly coded your `JFrame` project, it really shouldn't be too difficult to refactor. Have a look at [**Java Applets**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/index.html). You can see some of the examples and how they properly structure the code.

Comment: It would almost certainly require code changes, but the devil is in the details of how it is currently coded.  For example, does the current code extend `JFrame`?  Is the main part of the GUI put in a `JPanel`?  BTW - **Why** do you not wish to use Java Web Start to launch the existing frame?  It will likely be easier than converting the code to an applet.

Comment: because it needs to be in browser, not a new window and "public class Main extends Canvas implements Runnable {" i think that means no it doesnt extend jFrame, and i currently don't use Jpanel. i have a Github link to the entire project if it would make it easier.

Answer (score 0):

When I code Swing applications, I usually create a class which extends JPanel and set up the UI inside this class. That way I can add the JPanel to any container I wish. I can either add it to a JFrame or a JApplet with very minimal effort.